# How to make a sticky footer using flexbox in IE11?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to make a simple design with flexbox but I'm having trouble with IE11. Basically, I want a footer that sticks to the bottom only if the content is not high enough. I have no issue doing that with Chrome like this:

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Just play with the number of `<p>main</p>` to see the wrong behaviour with IE11.

Is there a way to achieve this without JavaScript?

Comment: Does not work. In this case, "Footer" appears directly below "Header" on the top of "Main".

Comment: Ah right yes, you can just change your flex:1 to flex-grow:1 and that should work

Answer (score 32, accepted):

IE has a `min-height` bug and needs `display: flex` on the flex column containers parent, in this case the `html`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2b7urf67/)

Update your CSS like this

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
body {
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: The `min-height` bug wasn't the issue in this case. But `flex-grow: 1` does the trick because when you remove `flex: 1` it resets `flex-basis` to the  `auto` default.

Comment: @Michael_B I figured that one out just now, after your comment by your answer, so thanks again

Comment: @Asons so update your answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44700256/4854931) must be the accepted answer

Comment: @Alex78191 -- Agree, it should, and mine still point to another issue IE has, which also has some value for users, hence I'll left it as is, and given IE is more or less gone, it really doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 10):

On `main`, instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: auto`. That should be all you need.

---

The `flex: 1` shorthand rule breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

The `flex: auto` shorthand rule breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto`

IE has trouble parsing `flex-basis: 0`.

More information:

- [flex property not working in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276)

Comment: This works too..+1. Still, how come `flex: auto` becomes `1 1 auto` when the default is `0 1 auto`?

Comment: Aha, thanks....really missed that before, thought it only changed the flex basis (I belong to the older generation and we don't read manuals :)

Answer (score 7):

A solution that really helped me (may not be applicable in all cases) is adding an arbitrary fixed height in pixels - the min-height overrides the fixed height so there's no cropped content. Here's a CSS example:

```css
.fullheight {
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: 200px; /*IE 11 flexbox min-height fix*/
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this might be a desired solution: if you don't necessarily want grow the `main` tag but still align the footer at the bottom:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
  <p>Main</p>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: `flex-grow: 1;` is not needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This answer ([@ceindeg answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51023941/5552686)) partially worked for me, but shrunk the parent container size, and I had a background I wanted to position at the bottom.

---

So I just went to `position: absolute` for the footer **only** for IE.

You can use a media-query only for IE, so the other browsers work fine (take a look here: [How to target only IE (any version) within a stylesheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28419263/5552686)).

In my case, I wanted to aim IE10 and IE11, so I used this:

```css
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
  footer {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
  }


  .parent-container {
    position: relative
    // Add some padding-bottom to the parent container so it won't be glued together
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
}
```