# Making flexbox work in IE11

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I know there are similar questions about, but I have tried all of the suggestions and still cant get it working.  I am using Bootstrap, and I have a section that is 100vh in height. Within this section I have two rows, the second row I needed placing at the very bottom of the section, but did not want to use absolute positioning. As such, I used the flex system.

My layout was like so

```css
.mn120 {
  min-height: 120px;
}

img {
  max-width: 40%;
}

.mh100vh {
  min-height: 900px;
}

.col-md-4 {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="someSection" class="section">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-between fHeight mh100vh">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
  <h2 class="section-title">Header Text</h2>
  <p class="section-subtitle">
    Some Text
  </p>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row d-flex fHeight">
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <img class="btmImg" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
  <img class="btmImg" src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png" alt="" />
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I made use of a lot of Bootstrap classes to help me achieve this layout. To demonstrate the issue, I have changed the height of the section to 900px rather than 100vh

So, if you view this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/66/) in something like chrome, you will see that the image row sits at the bottom of the section. However, if you view it in IE11, you will see that the image row does not sit at the bottom of the section.

Is there any way to make this layout work within IE11?

Comment: I'm running it in IE and Chrome with the same effect https://www.screencast.com/t/IK6mgEbk See the screenshot

Comment: From the looks of your screenshot, you are displaying it in tablet view.  If you increase the width of the browser, the images should be on the same row, not stacked.  Thanks

Comment: You should specify this in your question by the way, but either way, here is a full screen screenshot in IE https://www.screencast.com/t/UZblTMhTB6

Comment: Thats definitely not displaying correctly for you.  The two images should be next to each other, not stacked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do these 2 things to make it render the same cross browsers:

- IE has a [`min-height` bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700068/flexbox-min-height-and-ie11) when using flex *column* direction, adding `display: flex` to its parent (`section`) solves that
- IE also have [some issues when it comes to auto margins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534254/flex-auto-margin-not-working-in-ie10-11), so instead of `margin-top: auto` on the `.col-md-4` item, use `align-items: flex-end` on the parent (`row d-flex fHeight`)

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z69w9u4g/70/)

Stack snippet

```css
.section {
  display: flex;               /*  added  */
}

.row.d-flex.fHeight {
  align-items: flex-end;       /*  added  */
}

.mn120 {
  min-height: 120px;
}

img {
  max-width: 40%;
}

.mh100vh {
  min-height: 900px;
}

/*
.col-md-4 {
  margin-top:auto;
}
*/
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="someSection" class="section">
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-between fHeight mh100vh">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
        <h2 class="section-title">Header Text</h2>
        <p class="section-subtitle">
          Some Text
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex fHeight">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="btmImg" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5BcV.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <img class="btmImg" src="http://www.atfund.gatech.edu/sites/default/files/images/verticalplaceholderimage-440x680.png" alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using Bootstrap 4 class `.d-flex` with `min-height: 350px;` which have no-spacing/height issue for container in IE11. Fixed by adding height to the flex container.

**Try adding height**

```
height: 350px;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to this.
I would recommend to **use your own .d-flex class**.

I've implemented this sass script: https://gist.github.com/richardtorres314/26b18e12958ba418bb37993fdcbfc1bd

```
.d-flex-new {
  @include flexbox();
  width: 100%;
}
```

This in combination with the two options from @Ason