# Using d-flex and flex-wrap in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have seen that this question had been asked before and I tried the different answers provided, however, none seemed to work on my code.
I am working on fixing a series of inputs that are displaying in two columns in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE11.

This is how it looks on Chrome

[image]

This is how it looks on IE11

[image]

Here is the code being used

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
    <div *ngFor="let field of fieldsToDisplay;let i = index"
         ng-class="'address-single-div-class w-100': field.FieldType.toString() == FieldType_Type.Textarea.toString(), 'address-single-div-class': field">
        <input-field 
            *** series of inputs ***
        </input-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the answers that you tried but didn't work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137289/making-flexbox-work-in-ie11 that eventually led me to another solution that is linked by an user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I fixed my problem by adding `width:50%` to the second div that has the input fields. You can see the image I attached in my question for reference.
Apparently, `flex-wrap` doesn't do its job properly in IE11 due to some bugs. So instead of wrapping the elements, IE11 expands the container. By adding the width I predefined the container's size, that way it actually wraps the input fiels AND give them the full input size, so I do not need to use `flex-fill`. Plus, it doesn't affect the display in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Congratulation. I suggest you to try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `col-*` classes for the input fields, please check the following sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container mt-3"> 
        <p>Use .flex-fill on flex items to force them into equal widths:</p>
        <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="p-2 flex-fill form-control col-4" value="Flex item 1" />
            <input type="text" class="p-2 flex-fill form-control col-4" value="Flex item 2" />
            <input type="text" class="p-2 flex-fill form-control col-4" value="Flex item 3" /> 
            <input type="text" class="p-2 flex-fill form-control col-4" value="Flex item 4" /> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The result in IE11 browser:

[image]

Comment: Oh I already fixed the problem, which I am going to write the answer for, but thank you for replying :), this coulld be an alternative way of fixing it.